# iCloud+CoreData - "Ubiquity: Librarian" error log

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud

I'm using `iCloud+CoreData` as a persistent stack for my app.
The issue comes out when my app is being installed on the second device.

I see the error log during the on-boarding phase and the error seems to affect both devices.

During the on-boarding I perform the "addPersistentStoreWithType" on my `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` that triggers the iCloud Initial Seed download (if exists).

**The "options" parameter for the iCloud store are the following:**

---

```
 NSDictionary *options =@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @YES, 
                          NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @YES,
                          NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey: "PersistentStore_iCloud",
                          NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"}};
```

---

**The "URL" parameter used in the "addPersistentStoreWithType" method is the following:**

---

```
  NSURL *docUrl = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                    URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory 
                    inDomains:NSUserDomainMask]lastObject];

NSURL *cloudStore = [[docUrl URLByAppendingPathComponent:"PersistentStore_iCloud"] 
                     URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"sqlite"];
```

---

**After that I see the following error in the XCode logged for both devices (on the first device appears a bit later):**

---

> 2015-07-03 11:14:37.362 Quadro[4110:1837886]
>   __45-[PFUbiquityFilePresenter processPendingURLs]_block_invoke(439): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Librarian returned a serious error for starting
>   downloads Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (BRCloudDocsErrorDomain error 5 - No document
>   at URL)" UserInfo=0x171276940 {NSDescription=No document at URL,
>   NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Library/Mobile
>   Documents/iCloud~me~actions~Quadro/CoreData/PersistentStore_iCloud/.baseline/PersistentStore_iCloud/Le0RVMmU~RX4wGSl7Dd6sM81tBZId1iVh~Wp_~6U~4U=/baseline.zip,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x171258600 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No
>   such file or directory"} with userInfo {
>       NSDescription = "No document at URL";
>       NSFilePath = "/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~me~actions~Quadro/CoreData/PersistentStore_iCloud/.baseline/PersistentStore_iCloud/Le0RVMmU~RX4wGSl7Dd6sM81tBZId1iVh~Wp_~6U~4U=/baseline.zip";
>       NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"
>   UserInfo=0x171278800 {NSDescription=No such file or directory}"; } for
>   these urls: (
>       "file:///var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~me~actions~Quadro/CoreData/PersistentStore_iCloud/.baseline/PersistentStore_iCloud/Le0RVMmU~RX4wGSl7Dd6sM81tBZId1iVh~Wp_~6U~4U=/baseline.zip"
>   )

---

**Conclusion**

Sometimes, when the error comes out, Data is not synced completely, sometimes yes.

Both devices use a really reliable WiFi 
I noticed that the system is trying to retrieve the "baseline.zip” using this directory:

> "/var/mobile/Library/Mobile
>
> Documents/iCloud~me~actions~Quadro/CoreData/PersistentStore_iCloud/.baseline/PersistentStore_iCloud/38Bj4gxLeIZNVMjIuPeKljVslTu~kP0UhpAvrkvKXOM=/baseline.zip"

Browsing the device file system folders (with iExplorer or similar utility tool) I found out that this directory does not exist in the device file system.

I use iOS Version 8.3 (12F69) with an Apple iPad mini 2 (A1489) and an iPhone6 (A1586).

--

Any suggestion would be appreciated, I'm struggling on this.
Thanks.

Comment: Check the apps iCloud container on your Mac (you will need to use Terminal) to see what files are actually in iCloud.  Also make sure you have given enough time for the files to sync.  And then log a bug with Apple.

Comment: Tried many times and already opened a Bug Report. Apple dev just ignores for now. I opened the question here with the hope for a work-around . Thanks

Comment: Try removing the app from all devices and all simulator devices, then delete the iCloud container (you will need to use terminal commands to delete everything from the container), now reinstall the app on one sim device and load some data, verify that the files are created in the iCloud container (check using a Mac as the Mac will download the files immediately they become available in iCloud). Now install the app on another device sim device and verify the files get downloaded to the sim device container.